# How to pass other data with j_security_check?

Tags: websphere-6.1, j-security-check

I use IBM Websphere Application Server 6.1 and my login screen have controls as:

```
  <form action="j_security_check" method="POST">

     User Name:      [ Admin         ] <<-- j_username
     Password:       [ *******       ] <<-- j_password
     Operation Date: [ 10/Nov/2011   ] <<---txtOperDate
              [Login] [Cancel]

   </form>
```

How to get Operation Date value in other pages after authentication with `j_security_check`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's better to send that parameter along with Cookies in header. Than inside j_security_form.

Thanks
J